# Java - Subtracting time without if statements

Tags: java, math, time

This is my first question here, so bear with me and I hope I can get some feedback on my question itself as well as an answer. Here goes:

I had an assignment to get time in the form of an integer like this: 173025 for 17h, 30min, 25sec.

So far so good. Now though I have to subtract one time from the other. If the subtracted time is bigger, it should loop around to 24 hours when it reaches zero and continue subtracting from there. I managed to implement this with code that looks like this:

> ```
> public void subtract(int minuser) {
>     time = time - timmy(minuser); 
>     
>     if (time < 0) {
>         time = 24*60*60 + time;
> ```

I left out all the bits about converting the time to seconds and converting it back to hours, minutes and seconds, all of that works fine. What the unfortunately named timmy method does is basically just to convert the time variable "minuser" (which is the time that is supposed to be subtracted) from the user input to seconds.

I just can't figure out how to do this without using an if statement.

Comment: So you had to an `if` statement: what's wrong with that?  `if` statements aren't something to be feared, avoided, or ashamed of...

Comment: Not using if statements was part of the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Just use integer modulo operator (when time is in seconds)

```
time = (24*60*60 + time) % (24*60*60);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I get how the concept works now. For some weird reason this breaks my code though. I guess I'll try to figure out why now.

Comment: I "fixed" it by adding brackets to make sure order of operations is correct. It looks like this now: > time = 24*60*60 + time - timmy(minuser) % (24*60*60);

Comment: My code refers to time after subtraction and it does contain brackets around (24*60*60)

Comment: You are of course correct. I used the other answer's code and didn't notice the difference in brackets between theirs and yours.

Comment: It is worth to make constant like SecondsInDay  and use it (to avoid magical numbers and mistakes). I think that Java already has  similar in time stuff libraries

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep this in mind for future actual use!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void subtract(int minuser) {
    time = (24*60*60 + time - timmy(minuser)) % (24*60*60);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I had to think for a while but now this seems to make sense. For some weird reason it appears to break my code though. I'll try to figure it out, but I get how the concept works.

Comment: I "fixed" it by adding brackets to make sure order of operations is correct. It looks like this now:

> time = 24*60*60 + time - timmy(minuser) % (24*60*60);

Comment: @Fabs ah - yes the brackets. I've edited the answer.